# How to pprint the result of a function in clojure?

Tags: clojure

When I use pprint with a function call, I do not get the result of the function:

```
(defn my-func [] (+ 1 2))
(pprint my-func)
```

Instead I get no output at all. How do I make pprint print 3?

Answer (score 2):

`my-func` evaluates to the `fn` refered to by the var `my-func`, you should see an output of the form

```
#object[user$my_func 0x50029372 "user$my_func@50029372"]
```

to invoke `my-func` you need to use

```
(my-func)
```

so you can `pprint` the result with

```
(pprint (my-func))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try one of the many helpers that people have built to get better insight into their functions (apart from using a debugger).

Here's a recent one that helps you printing out most results very easily (by using reader macros):
https://github.com/weavejester/hashp